# res_query() sometimes hangs, Android 4.4 (level 19) NDK

Tags: android, dns, android-ndk

I'm running a simple line of code to look up a DNS name:

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "dns", "DNS query: %s", name);
if ((responseLen = res_query(name, 1, 1, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) < 0) {
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "dns", "DNS query failed");
  goto query_error;
}
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "dns", "DNS query success");
```

I tested on Android 4.4 level 19.

I obtained the name from the WIFI interface, and it seems to be correct.

Some of the time it prints "DNS query success". It never prints "DNS query failed".

What I find is that *some* of the times this prints only "DNS query: blahblah" and just hangs. If that happens it will hang repeatedly.

If it works it will work repeatedly too. Then it will stop working all of a sudden. It's like the tide; when it's high you can navigate but when it's low you can't.

I've verified that the buffer is big enough (4KB).

I've also verified that there are NO DNS query being made when it hangs (tried capturing packets with Wireshark; nothing is captured).

I've tried on Android 4.0 (level 14) and it was working fine.

Why would res_query() just hang like that?

Comment: responseLen is not unsigned, right?

Comment: @auselen responseLen is an int, so yes.

Comment: I don't see res_query() hang (Android 4.4 level 19), but I've yet to see it return anything besides "Unknown resolver error" and "Host name lookup failure" regardless of the URL I pass it.